# docker-compose exec on running container with arguments

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to use the **existing container** multiple times by providing **different** arguments. I have a `docker-compose.yml` file with `entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]`.

To run the container I use the command `docker-compose run foo --database=foo --schema=boo --tables=puah`. It works perfect. Container does the job.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
   bcp:
      image: ubuntu:18.04
      restart: always
      tty: true
      entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "/ingestion/bcp-entrypoint.sh"]
      volumes:
          - ./services/bcp:/ingestion/services/bcp
          - ./bcp-entrypoint.sh:/ingestion/bcp-entrypoint.sh
```

Here is the `bcp-entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

INGESTION_DIR=/ingestion
TMP_DIR=/tmp/ingestion

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get clean -y
apt-get install -y python3-pip
apt-get install -y curl

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list

apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev

cd ${INGESTION_DIR}
mkdir ${TMP_DIR}

python3 -m --database $database --schmema $schema --tables ${TABLES}
```

My problems:

1. The container restarts all the time and keeps retrieving the data with the same arguments provided in `docker-compose run bcp ...`?
2. I would like to use one container and overwrite the arguments, so I can skip costly installation.

Maybe there is a combination of `entrypoint & command` in `docker-compose.yml`? So, basically, I would like to execute `python3 -m --database ... --schema ... --tables ...`. Ideally I would do it purely in docker-compose without a `dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to use the existing container multiple times by providing different arguments.

If you want to change `entrypoint` or `cmd` of an already existing container, you can't. Once a container is created, most of its configuration cannot be changed (see [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) for updatable container configs)

Keep in mind:

- `docker-compose run` will create and start a container with given arguments (you can then override `entrypoint` or `cmd`)
- `docker-compose exec` run a command in a running container. It won't work in a stopped container, and won't create a new container.
- `docker start` start a stopped container, the container will start with already defined `cmd` and `entrypoint`. You won't be able to change that.

You can do something like `docker-compose run --entrypoint 'sleep 9999' foo` which will start your container and ensure it's running for 9999 seconds, then execute commands with `docker-compose exec` such as

```
# similar to what would happen with 'docker-compose run foo --database=foo --schema=boo' considering entrypoint is ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]'
# '--database=foo --schema=boo' would be passed as argument of entrypoint.sh
docker-compose exec "/bin/bash -c 'entrypoint.sh --database=foo --schema=boo'"
docker-compose exec "/bin/bash -c 'entrypoint.sh --database=blah --schema=wooow'"
```

Comment: Can I use `tty: true` instead? In the `docker-compose.yml`. Unfortunately the command does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have updated the question. Now, you have more transparency! Maybe that will help!

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose run` is using an image to create a container with the provided arguments.

Use `docker-compose run foo --name foo1 --[other arguments]` to end up with a container for each set of arguments.

If you don't want to keep the container once the job is done then include the `-rm` option to remove the container on close.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The point is, I do want to use one container once created after `run` command, since there is a lot packages to be installed in the container as per `entrypoint.sh`. Thus, if I `docker-compose run ...` every time, it will take a lot of time to install all these packages to run a single command. To avoid this, I want to use existing container with different arguments - i.e., no need to create another container from the image.

Comment: If you're installing packages, you probably want to do it via a Dockerfile, so it will get done just once.  Once you've done that, creating new containers from the image should be fairly cheap.

Comment: I take the image of ubuntu and then do `apt-get install ...` in `entrypoint.sh`. If I do `docker-compose run -service-` then new container is created and all packages are installed another time (since a new container). That is why I avoid `--rm` while creating a container.